# Gitlab webhook to Docker Container running Jenkins hosted on home network

Tags: docker, jenkins, gitlab, webhooks

I have an Ubuntu server running 2 docker containers one is running Jenkins and the other one is running Sonarqube. My school has a private gitlab server from this server I want to create an webhook to my Jenkins to trigger a build but the following error is coming up.. And I Don't know what is going on...

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XAqvJ.png)

Both port forwarded via router using the following ports:
jenkins xx.xx.xx.xxx:8080
sonarqube xx.xx.xx.xxx:8090

Getting the following error when testing the webhook using the by jenkins provided url to trigger: http://xx.xx.xx.xxx:8080/project/some_project

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FsYnU.png)

Does it have to do with docker?

Comment: Your home computer is not exposed to the internet. The IP you are using is the IP of connection point of home internet. Also school gitlab server might have restrictions to access internet out side of school network.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I dont understand can you clarify that for me. because I can access it from for example my work not only when I am home?

Comment: Is the Ubuntu server running at your home? Are you able to ping Ubuntu server from the school network?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya yes the server is running at my home and I am able to ping it from another network like school

Comment: Did you solve the problem?